# 401 Error when accessing API

Tags: c#, xml, json, api, xmlhttprequest

I see several responses to this issue however none seem to work in my case. Here is the situation.

I'm working with the API from thetvdb.com.

I am loading XML via API. If I run the application it will give me a 401 error. If I load the URL in IE first then run the application it loads fine.

I suspect its a cookie issue but I am not sure how to pass that cookie during my request below.

```
var _doc = new XmlDocument();
_doc.Load(_url);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The API is thetvdb.com and authentication is done via an API key.

Comment: There are no credentials other than an API key to pass, I have tried sending header information as well without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP error 401 means "unauthorized".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_401#4xx_Client_Error)

It means you need to contact the people providing the API and ask them how to authenticate.

***It's different with every provider.***
The right people to ask are the ones that provide the web services/API.

Comment: However, as a GUESS I'd say it's probably done via a Certificate.  The fact that IE recognized it, but the .NET runtime doesn't suggestests a certificate is used to authenticate you, and the cert is recognized by IE but not the .NET Runtime.

Comment: The API is thetvdb.com and authentication is done via an API key.

Comment: So nobody has run into this issue?

Comment: I've run into it with three different vendors, and the solution was different for each one.  I've never used thetvdb.com, but I stand by my originan answer that "right people to ask are the ones that provide the web services/API".

Answer (score 1):

After much reading and trial and error I have figured this out. I have tested this with several sites.

```
WebRequest _wr = WebRequest.Create(_url);
_wr.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
_wr.PreAuthenticate = true;
_wr.GetResponse();
//do your stuff
_wr.Dispose();
```

This seems to replicate the steps of me manually opening a browser and navigating to the page to prevent the 401 error when I launched my app. I hope this helps someone else as I understand the frustration.